# Relation between hamiltonian perturbation theory (classical) and the Fokker Planck drift and diffusion coefficients?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have a hamiltonian of the form
$$
H(q,p) = H_0 + \epsilon H_1(q,p)
$$

In perturbation theory we approximate the solution to the equations of motion as a power series in $\epsilon$:

$$
q(t) = q_0(t) + \epsilon q_1(t) + \epsilon^2 q_2(t) + ...
$$
(and similar for p).

In the Fokker Planck approximation we obtain drift and diffusion coefficients for the space-density function P(x,t), which is a velocity integral of the full distribution function f(x,v,t). My question is: when one does perturbation theory, is there any relationship between the order $\epsilon$ and higher terms above to the drift/diffusion coefficients that can be obtained from the Fokker-Planck approximation? I.e., does the order $\epsilon^2$ term have any relation to the diffusion coefficient?